# Microsoft Graph API url vs SharePoint ALM REST API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-rest-api

Microsoft graph urls and SharePoint rest api urls are like this

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites  - https://{tenant-name}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/sites
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives - https://{tenant-name}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drives
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive  - https://{tenant-name}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/lists  - https://{tenant-name}.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/lists
```

I generates access token for sharepoint using graph api and need to know corresponsing graph url of following

`https://{tenant-name}.sharepoint.com/_api/web/{scope}appcatalog/AvailableApps`

such as 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/web/tenantappcatalog/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no such endpoint for graph api.

You have to use sharepoint rest api to get the information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/alm-api-for-spfx-add-ins?tabs=sprest